# jQuery display input and select options in realtime in a span

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that has several input and select elements. At the end of the form I'm displaying a summary of what the user has inputed/selected - I'd like this to change in realtime i.e. as the user makes changes.

Here is part of my form:

```
<select class="select" id="eventType" name="eventType">
    <option vlaue="0"></option>
    <option value="0">Wedding</option>
    <option value="0">Private Party</option>
    <option value="0">Corporate Event</option>
 </select>
```

And the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(".txt, .select, .checkbox").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function(){
    createSummary();
        });
    });

function createSummary() {
    var eventType = $("#eventType").val();      
    $(".summary_eventType").html(eventType);

}
```

However this just returns the value 0 not the actual text that is selected.

Comment: because your all option has value set to `0`

Comment: Also you can trim that entire first part to `$(".txt, .select, .checkbox").change(createSummary);`

Comment: If you leave out the `value="0"` attribute, the values will automatically be set to the text content. Why do you set values if you're not using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of selected option use `.html()`

```
var eventType = $("#eventType option:selected").html();
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SXwuz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what else would you like to get from this?:

```
<select class="select" id="eventType" name="eventType">
  <option vlaue="0"></option>
  <option value="0">Wedding</option>
  <option value="0">Private Party</option>
  <option value="0">Corporate Event</option>
</select>
```

This will provide the values as zero, as they all have the `0` set as their value. Using some value would minimize the error.

Set some value like this:

```
<select class="select" id="eventType" name="eventType">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Wedding</option>
  <option value="2">Private Party</option>
  <option value="3">Corporate Event</option>
</select>
```

Also, note that you are having `vlaue` in the first option. That's not the correct method! You need to use `value`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The value for all your option is set as `O`

In each of these options below, `value` is set to `zero`

```
<option value="0">Wedding</option> // see value='0'
 <option value="0">Private Party</option>
<option value="0">Corporate Event</option>
```

either you can change this to

```
<option value="Wedding">Wedding</option> // 
     <option value="Private Party">Private Party</option>
    <option value="Corporate Event">Corporate Event</option>
```

working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/qGGEX/1/)**

### **or**

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/qGGEX/)

change the code

```
function createSummary() {
    var eventType = $("#eventType option:selected").text() // changed code
    $(".summary_eventType").html(eventType);

}
```